# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dangerous-request

I am getting this error in my ASP.NET MVC application where I am taking HTML input from a WYSIWYG so I don't want the content validated.

I have attempted the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) but it seems to make no difference in my MVC application. I have also tried doing it in the web.config but again - no joy. 
 Is this a bug in ASP.NET MVC or something?

Comment: Kelix, the post you refer to carries with it the recommendation to use the [pages requestValidation="false"] web.config paramater or the [@Page ValidateRequest="False"] attribute of the View.  Any one of these options should work fine.

Comment: It doesn't, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486408/can-a-pages-validaterequest-setting-be-overridden

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In MVC you would use the [ValidateInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx)(false) attribute.

You then need to sanitize your inputs, e.g. with something like [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/) (built in to ASP.NET 4.5+; use NuGet package for earlier).

Comment: you must also have <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/> in web.config

Comment: [AllowHtml] on the model property is even better if you can.

Comment: Disabling validation is NOT the secure way to do this, especially if your app is facing public Internet. Consider using a more granular `[AllowHtml]` attibute

Comment: @jazzcat I agree, but `[AllowHtml]` didn't exist in 2009

Answer (score 29):

In MVC 3 and later, you can also use the `[AllowHtml]` attribute. This attribute allows you to be more granular by skipping validation for only one property on your model.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: Worked for me, this seems safer than '[ValidateInput(false)]', thank you

Comment: Had to apply to the model attributes as well the corresponding view model attributes, then it worked.

Comment: Using this attribute  [AllowHtml] in my model, got rid of the error.  Will it still catch  cross site scripting?

Comment: No, it will not catch cross-site scripting. Opting into this attribute either means that you will be safely encoding the contents yourself before outputting them, or you are developing an HTML editor for some sort of CMS where you actually want to allow the user to enter HTML/scripts with the intention of running them.

Answer (score 21):

Just place this attribute: [ValidateInput(false)] on the action method on the controller that handles the form post.

Answer (score 4):

use `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in web config

Comment: http://www.asp.net/(S(ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg))/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes/#_TOC7

Answer (score 1):

In your controller action method, (the one which is bringing this) add [ValidateInput(false)]

Example

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Insert(FormCollection formCollection, Models.Page page)
    {
        //your code
        return View();
    }
```