# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (editor="<div id="header" sty...")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, rich-text-editor, richtextediting

First of all I should say I have followed almost all the Questions and forum Post below

[Stackoverflow Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

[Stackoverflow Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455528/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client-asp-ne)

[Stackoverflow Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130186/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

[Stackoverflow Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591429/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client-textbox)

[aspsnippets.com](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Error-A-potentially-dangerous-RequestForm-value-was-detected-from-the-client.aspx)

[Server Error in Application ... A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_vbnet_server_error_potentially_dangerous.htm)

[Avoiding the ‘A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected’](http://codingstill.com/2013/01/avoiding-the-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected/)

[c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/15506/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from.aspx)

[A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client in asp.net](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/potentially-dangerous-requestform-value.html)

all the thread mentioned to add  `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode = "2.0" />` or `<pages validateRequest ="false" />` inside the web.config file , but this isn't working for me .

Once I did that and start debugging ,  getting this kind of error

[image]

Actually I'm trying to is Loading a HTML file into Rich Text Editor content then Once I click **Save as PDF** button saving that Rich Text Editor content to PDF file

these are the relevant controller class methods

```
   [ValidateInput(false)]  
      public ActionResult output_xhtml()  
      {  
          PrepairEditor(delegate(Editor editor)  
          {  
              editor.LoadHtml("~/example.html");  
          });  
          return View();  
      }  

      [HttpPost]  
      [ValidateInput(false)]  
      public ActionResult output_xhtml(string m)  
      {  
          Editor theeditor = PrepairEditor(delegate(Editor editor)  
          {  

          });  

          theeditor.SavePDF("~/aaa.pdf");  

          return View();  
      }
```

PrepairEditor() method

```
protected Editor PrepairEditor(Action<Editor> oninit)  
  {  
      Editor editor = new Editor(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, "editor");  

      editor.ClientFolder = "/richtexteditor/";  
      editor.ContentCss = "/Content/example.css";  
      //editor.ClientFolder = "/Content/richtexteditor/";      
      //editor.ClientFolder = "/Scripts/richtexteditor/";      

      editor.Text = "Type here";  

      editor.AjaxPostbackUrl = Url.Action("EditorAjaxHandler");  

      if (oninit != null) oninit(editor);  

      //try to handle the upload/ajax requests      
      bool isajax = editor.MvcInit();  

      if (isajax)  
          return editor;  

      //load the form data if any      
      if (this.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")  
      {  
          string formdata = this.Request.Form[editor.Name];  
          if (formdata != null)  
              editor.LoadFormData(formdata);  
      }  

      //render the editor to ViewBag.Editor      
      ViewBag.Editor = editor.MvcGetString();  

      return editor;  
  }  

  //this action is specified by editor.AjaxPostbackUrl = Url.Action("EditorAjaxHandler");      
  //it will handle the editor dialogs Upload/Ajax requests      
  [ValidateInput(false)]  
  public ActionResult EditorAjaxHandler()  
  {  
      PrepairEditor(delegate(Editor editor)  
      {  

      });  
      return new EmptyResult();  
  }
```

this is screenshot of error occurring place in  PrepairEditor() method

[image]

**output_xhtml.cshtml** view file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RichTextEditor - Output XHTML</title>    
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var editor;

    function RichTextEditor_OnLoad(editor) {
        editor = editor;
            var content = true;
            if (!content) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    editor.SetText("<table>.....</table>");
                }, 1000);
                return;
            }
        }

    </script>


    <script type='text/javascript'>

    function RichTextEditor_OnLoad(editor) {
        editor.SetWidth(1150); //Sets the width.
        editor.SetHeight(612); //Sets the height.
    }

    </script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {           

            <div>
                @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Editor)
                <br />
                <button id="btn_sumbit" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger submit">Save as PDF</button>                   
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <h3>
                    Result html:
                </h3>
                <div>
                    @ViewBag._content
                </div>
            </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once I did that and start debugging , getting this kind of error

Look at the error you are getting. You already have a `<httpRuntime />` section in your web.config. You can't have two of them. Instead of adding a new one, change the existing one.

Comment: yeah thats the mistake, my bad

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are passing HTML

add: `[AllowHtml]` above your method

Comment: which method `output_xhtml()`or `PrepairEditor()` ?

Comment: output_xhtml()

Thats the method you are posting the HTML to.

Comment: Nope once I did that geting red squiggly lline error under `[AllowHtml]` tag in VS

this is error definition then `Attribute 'AllowHtml' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations.`

Comment: <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> in config to use this functionality. read the error...

Answer (score 0):

[AllowHtml] goes on the property in your model not the controller method. Its namespace is System.Web.MVC