# ValidateRequest="false" doesn't work when posting HTML values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing a personal blog in ASP.NET MVC 1.0. This blog application has Views like "Insert Post", "Edit Post", etc. I need to post a string containing HTML back to the appropriate controller method. That HTML value is being posted from a textarea.

I've read that it's necessary to disable `ValidateRequest` directly on the page with the attribute `ValidateRequest = "false"` or in the web.config file.

When I insert an HTML value in my textarea, I get always the error of 'potential value dangerous'.

How can I use `ValidateRequest` to allow the form element containing HTML values to be posted?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486408/can-a-pages-validaterequest-setting-be-overridden

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For ASP.Net MVC, you have to use the ValidateInput(false) Attribute on your Controller action like so:

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult SaveBodyCopy(int? id, string richTextEditor1)
```

Then the rest of your Controller action.